# Not able to solve Express Middleware issue

Tags: node.js

My first piece of code below:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer(express.logger());

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.send('Hello World 2');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Threw up the error:  "Most middleware (like logger) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately"

So I looked at StackOverflow, did npm install morgan, and changed my code to:

```
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = express.createServer(logger());

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.send('Hello World 2');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Now I get this error:

```
var app = express.createServer(logger());
                  ^
TypeError: Object function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };

  mixin(app, proto);
  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype);

  app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
  app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
  app.init();
  return app;
} has no method 'createServer'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create `app` with `express()`. Afterwards, you can setup any middleware (like `morgan` in this case) with `app.use`:

```
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = express();

app.use(logger());

...
```

`app.use()` documentation: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use. (Linking to Express 4.x documentation as not explicit what Express version you're running).

There is an exact same example like the one I wrote above in [Morgan's README](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `createServer` method has been removed from express.

use

```
app = express();
app.use(logger())
```

instead of

```
app = express.createServer(logger())
```

Many things got changed from express 3.0 to 4.0. You should have a look [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x)